# Issues with state machine in c

Tags: c, state-machine

I'm facing some issues with my state machine (function automate()). It seems that the enum always keep the same values instead of changing it depending on differents conditions in the function. 
My output is always "DECREMENT_PARA_1" Can anyone tell me why the variable etat_courant doesn't keep the value in memory for each iteration please ? Thanks in advance ! Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


//PARAMETRES
enum Etat {INIT, DECREMENT_PARA_1, INCREMENT_PARA_1, ETAT_INVARIANT_1, DECREMENT_PARA_2, ETAT_INVARIANT_2, INCREMENT_PARA_2, RADAR_SATURE};

//Prototypes
void automate(int tddv_estime, int tab_para_automate[][2], enum Etat *etat_courant, int* para_1_courant, int* para_2_courant);
void fct_test(int scenario[]);

int main()
{
    int scenario[15] = {21, 21, 20, 12, 12, 20, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 500};
    fct_test(scenario);
    return 0;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Fonction fct_test
-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void fct_test(int scenario[])
{
    int increment = 1;
    int tddv_estime;
    int para_1_courant = 10;
    int para_2_courant = 4;
    int para_1_min = 5;
    int para_1_max = 10;

    int para_2_min = 1;
    int para_2_max = 4;

    int tab_para_automate[2][2] = {{0}};
    int tab_para_application[1][3] = {{0}};

    tab_para_automate[0][0] = para_1_min;
    tab_para_automate[0][1] = para_1_max;
    tab_para_automate[1][0] = para_2_min;
    tab_para_automate[1][1] = para_2_max;

    tab_para_application[0][0] = para_1_courant;
    tab_para_application[0][1] = para_2_courant;
    tab_para_application[0][2] = increment;

    int i;
    enum Etat etat_courant = INIT;

    for (i=0 ; i<15 ; i++)
   {
        tddv_estime = scenario[i];
        printf("%d\n",scenario[i]);
        automate(tddv_estime, tab_para_automate, &etat_courant, &para_1_courant, &para_2_courant);
   }
   //}
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Fonction automate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void automate(int tddv_estime, int tab_para_automate[][2], enum Etat *etat_courant, int* para_1_courant, int* para_2_courant)
{
    int evenement;


    int tddv_worst = 20;

    if (tddv_estime < tddv_worst)
        evenement = 1; //Etat initial

    if (tddv_estime > tddv_worst)
        evenement = 2; //Decrement para1

    if (tddv_estime < tddv_worst &&  *para_1_courant<= tab_para_automate[0][1])
        evenement = 3; //Increment para1

    if (tddv_estime == tddv_worst)
        evenement = 4; //Etat Invariant 1

    if (tddv_estime > tddv_worst && *para_1_courant <=  tab_para_automate[0][0])
        evenement = 5; //Decrement para_2

    if (tddv_estime < tddv_worst &&  *para_2_courant <= tab_para_automate[1][1])
        evenement = 6; //Increment para2

    if (tddv_estime == tddv_worst)
        evenement = 7; //Etat Invariant 2

    if (tddv_estime > tddv_worst && *para_1_courant<=  tab_para_automate[0][0] && *para_2_courant<=  tab_para_automate[1][0])
        evenement = 8; //Etat radar sature


    switch (*etat_courant) {
        case INIT:
            switch(evenement)
            {
                case 1:
                    *etat_courant = INIT;
                    printf("ETAT_INITIAL\n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    *etat_courant = DECREMENT_PARA_1;
                    printf("DECREMENT_PARA_1\n");
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case DECREMENT_PARA_1:
            switch(evenement)
            {
                case 5:
                    *etat_courant = DECREMENT_PARA_2;
                    printf("DECREMENT_PARA_2\n");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    *etat_courant = ETAT_INVARIANT_1;
                    printf("ETAT_INVARIANT_1\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    *etat_courant = INCREMENT_PARA_1;
                    printf("INCREMENT_PARA_1\n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    *etat_courant = DECREMENT_PARA_1;
                    printf("DECREMENT_PARA_1\n");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case INCREMENT_PARA_1:
            switch(evenement)
            {
                case 4:
                    *etat_courant = ETAT_INVARIANT_1;
                    printf("ETAT_INVARIANT_1\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    *etat_courant = INCREMENT_PARA_1;
                    printf("INCREMENT_PARA_1\n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    *etat_courant = DECREMENT_PARA_1;
                    printf("DECREMENT_PARA_1\n");
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case ETAT_INVARIANT_1:
            switch(evenement)
            {
                case 2:
                    *etat_courant = DECREMENT_PARA_1;
                    printf("DECREMENT_PARA_1\n");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    *etat_courant = ETAT_INVARIANT_1;
                    printf("ETAT_INVARIANT_1\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    *etat_courant = INCREMENT_PARA_1;
                    printf("INCREMENT_PARA_1\n");
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case DECREMENT_PARA_2:
            switch(evenement)
            {
                case 5:
                    *etat_courant = DECREMENT_PARA_2;
                    printf("DECREMENT_PARA_2\n");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    *etat_courant = ETAT_INVARIANT_2;
                    printf("ETAT_INVARIANT_2\n");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    *etat_courant = INCREMENT_PARA_2;
                    printf("INCREMENT_PARA_2\n");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    *etat_courant = RADAR_SATURE;
                    printf("RADAR_SATURE\n");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case ETAT_INVARIANT_2:
            switch(evenement)
            {
                case 5:
                    *etat_courant = DECREMENT_PARA_2;
                    printf("DECREMENT_PARA_2\n");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    *etat_courant = ETAT_INVARIANT_2;
                    printf("ETAT_INVARIANT_2\n");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    *etat_courant = INCREMENT_PARA_2;
                    printf("INCREMENT_PARA_2\n");
                    break;
                }
                break;

        case INCREMENT_PARA_2:
            switch(evenement)
            {
                case 5:
                    *etat_courant = DECREMENT_PARA_2;
                    printf("DECREMENT_PARA_2\n");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    *etat_courant = ETAT_INVARIANT_2;
                    printf("ETAT_INVARIANT_2\n");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    *etat_courant = INCREMENT_PARA_2;
                    printf("INCREMENT_PARA_2\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    *etat_courant = INCREMENT_PARA_1;
                    printf("INCREMENT_PARA_1\n");
                    break;
            }
            break;
            default :
                exit(1);
                break;

    }

}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Where is `scenario` declared?

Comment: Forgot to put it in my original code, it's edited now

Comment: What you need is an if-else ladder in your automate() function instead of a series of disconnected `if` statements. That logic there is highly suspect, just print `evenement` and `*estat_courant` before `switch (*etat_courant)`.

Comment: I printed evenement and *etat_courant just before the switch (*etat_courant). In fact, the evemenent variable has the good value everytime, but the *etat_courant is always equal to 0

Comment: Any other ideas ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why the variable etat_courant doesn't keep the value in memory for each iteration please ?

It actually is keeping the value in memory: it can not do otherwise, `etat_courant` will be kept in memory until `fct_test(...)` returns. The reason the output is always `DECREMENT_PARA_1` is purely due to the logic in your `automate()` function.

For example, you have a redundant comparison in your `automate()` function - which is overriding a previous assignment of `evenement`.

```
if (tddv_estime == tddv_worst)
    evenement = 4; //Etat Invariant 1

// ...

if (tddv_estime == tddv_worst)
    evenement = 7; //Etat Invariant 2
```

If - and this is just hypothetical (whether or not this is the right thing to do depends on what you are trying to achieve) - you remove the second comparison, the output will vary at least once.

As an aside ... It is safer to pass the size of the array to your `fct_test(...)` function - as in

```
int main(void) {
    int scenario[] = {21, 21, 20, 12, 12, 20, 22, 22,
                    22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 500};
    fct_test(scenario, sizeof(scenario)/sizeof(scenario[0]));
    return 0;
}

void fct_test(int *scenario, size_t array_len) {
    // Etc. (ommitted for brevity )
    for (i = 0; i < array_len; i++) {
         tddv_estime = scenario[i];
         // etc.
    }
}
```

(Note that I added a `return 0` in your `main()` also - which you were missing.)

Comment: I removes the second redundant comparison, it doesn't change anything. Nevertheless i also tried your method, it doesn't help neither :/

Comment: @MathieuTSH: When I remove the second comparison it prints `ETAT_INVARIANT_1` on two occasions. In any case, I wasn't proposing a "method" as such: I was pointing out that the problem is the logic in your `automate()` function - and that the value of `etat_courant` _is_ being preserved between iterations.

Comment: I finally get sometimes the state "ETAT_INVARIANT_1" but i never get others states i'm supposed to get, like "INCREMENT_PARA_1" for example. What's wrong with my logic ?